# Não consigo chamar uma função de um Service dentro de outro Service com Angular (NGX-ROCKET)

Tags: angular

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em Angular a partir do NGX-Rocket. E estou utilizando o serviço de autenticação já implementado no NGX.

No arquivo **app/core/http/http.service.ts** estou importando um Service localizado em **app/core/authentication/credentials.service.ts** e tentando utilizar a função `refreshToken()` localizada no 'credentials.service.ts'.

Porém, ao executar nada acontece. Nenhum erro é exibido e também a função não parece ser executada.

Abaixo seguem os dois arquivos que estou trabalhando.

Ps: Isso acontece em todos os arquivos de service do projeto. Já nos `components` eu consigo chamar as funções dos services normalmente.

**CREDENTIAL.SERVICE**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export interface Credentials {
  // Customize received credentials here
  email: string;
  token: string;
  expiration?: number;
}

const credentialsKey = 'credentials';

/**
 * Provides storage for authentication credentials.
 * The Credentials interface should be replaced with proper implementation.
 */
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CredentialsService {
  private _credentials: Credentials | null = null;

  constructor() {
    const savedCredentials = sessionStorage.getItem(credentialsKey) || localStorage.getItem(credentialsKey);
    if (savedCredentials) {
      this._credentials = JSON.parse(savedCredentials);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Checks is the user is authenticated.
   * @return True if the user is authenticated.
   */
  isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    return !!this.credentials;
  }

  /**
   * Gets the user credentials.
   * @return The user credentials or null if the user is not authenticated.
   */
  get credentials(): Credentials | null {
    return this._credentials;
  }

  /**
   * Sets the user credentials.
   * The credentials may be persisted across sessions by setting the `remember` parameter to true.
   * Otherwise, the credentials are only persisted for the current session.
   * @param credentials The user credentials.
   * @param remember True to remember credentials across sessions.
   */
  setCredentials(credentials?: Credentials, remember?: boolean) {
    this._credentials = credentials || null;

    if (credentials) {
      const minutes = 1 * 60 * 1000;
      const expiration = Date.now() + minutes;

      credentials.expiration = expiration; //set expiration

      const storage = remember ? localStorage : sessionStorage;

      storage.setItem(credentialsKey, JSON.stringify(credentials));
    } else {
      sessionStorage.removeItem(credentialsKey);
      localStorage.removeItem(credentialsKey);
    }
  }

  refreshToken() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

**HTTP.SERVICE.TS**

```
import { Inject, Injectable, InjectionToken, Injector, Optional, Type } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { ErrorHandlerInterceptor } from './error-handler.interceptor';
import { CacheInterceptor } from './cache.interceptor';
import { ApiPrefixInterceptor } from './api-prefix.interceptor';
import { CredentialsService } from './../authentication/credentials.service';

// HttpClient is declared in a re-exported module, so we have to extend the original module to make it work properly
// (see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13897)
declare module '@angular/common/http/http' {
  // Augment HttpClient with the added configuration methods from HttpService, to allow in-place replacement of
  // HttpClient with HttpService using dependency injection
  export interface HttpClient {
    /**
     * Enables caching for this request.
     * @param forceUpdate Forces request to be made and updates cache entry.
     * @return The new instance.
     */
    cache(forceUpdate?: boolean): HttpClient;

    /**
     * Skips default error handler for this request.
     * @return The new instance.
     */
    skipErrorHandler(): HttpClient;

    /**
     * Do not use API prefix for this request.
     * @return The new instance.
     */
    disableApiPrefix(): HttpClient;
  }
}

// From @angular/common/http/src/interceptor: allows to chain interceptors
class HttpInterceptorHandler implements HttpHandler {
  constructor(private next: HttpHandler, private interceptor: HttpInterceptor) {}

  handle(request: HttpRequest<any>): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.interceptor.intercept(request, this.next);
  }
}

/**
 * Allows to override default dynamic interceptors that can be disabled with the HttpService extension.
 * Except for very specific needs, you should better configure these interceptors directly in the constructor below
 * for better readability.
 *
 * For static interceptors that should always be enabled (like ApiPrefixInterceptor), use the standard
 * HTTP_INTERCEPTORS token.
 */
export const HTTP_DYNAMIC_INTERCEPTORS = new InjectionToken<HttpInterceptor>('HTTP_DYNAMIC_INTERCEPTORS');

/**
 * Extends HttpClient with per request configuration using dynamic interceptors.
 */
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpService extends HttpClient {
  constructor(
    private httpHandler: HttpHandler,
    private injector: Injector,
    @Optional() @Inject(HTTP_DYNAMIC_INTERCEPTORS) private interceptors: HttpInterceptor[] = [],
    private credentialsService?: CredentialsService
  ) {
    super(httpHandler);

    if (!this.interceptors) {
      // Configure default interceptors that can be disabled here
      this.interceptors = [this.injector.get(ApiPrefixInterceptor), this.injector.get(ErrorHandlerInterceptor)];
    }
  }

  cache(forceUpdate?: boolean): HttpClient {
    const cacheInterceptor = this.injector
      .get(CacheInterceptor as Type<CacheInterceptor>)
      .configure({ update: forceUpdate });
    return this.addInterceptor(cacheInterceptor);
  }

  skipErrorHandler(): HttpClient {
    return this.removeInterceptor(ErrorHandlerInterceptor);
  }

  disableApiPrefix(): HttpClient {
    return this.removeInterceptor(ApiPrefixInterceptor);
  }

  // Override the original method to wire interceptors when triggering the request.
  request(method?: any, url?: any, options?: any): any {
    const credentials = this.credentialsService.credentials;

    if (credentials && Date.now() > credentials.expiration) {
      console.log('é maior');
      this.credentialsService.refreshToken;
    }

    const handler = this.interceptors.reduceRight(
      (next, interceptor) => new HttpInterceptorHandler(next, interceptor),
      this.httpHandler
    );
    return new HttpClient(handler).request(method, url, options);
  }

  private removeInterceptor(interceptorType: Type<HttpInterceptor>): HttpService {
    return new HttpService(
      this.httpHandler,
      this.injector,
      this.interceptors.filter(i => !(i instanceof interceptorType)),
      this.credentialsService
    );
  }

  private addInterceptor(interceptor: HttpInterceptor): HttpService {
    return new HttpService(
      this.httpHandler,
      this.injector,
      this.interceptors.concat([interceptor]),
      this.credentialsService
    );
  }
}
```

Será que tem algo haver com isso aqui?

> @Injectable({
>     providedIn: 'root'
>   })

Percebi que os arquivos não são chamados no `app.module.ts` e sim nesse `index.ts`

**Print da estrutura de arquivos:**

[image: Print da estrutura de arquivos]

Comment: Essa função parece bem simples e só retorna true, quando vc chama ela retorna true?

Answer (score 0):

Como o @Eduardo Vargas comentou, a função refreshToken apenas retorna um true.

Você chama essa função sem tratar o retorno (this.credentialsService.refreshToken;).

Visualmente nada irá acontecer mesmo, no lugar onde você chama o refreshToken você também colocou esse log "console.log('é maior');", ele aparece no seu log?